# In Clojure, when should we use a monad instead of a macro and vice-versa?

Tags: macros, clojure, monads

There are too many tutorials out there on monads that say... "Look! here is a case where we can use a  monad" or "This is what a  monad is for". What I want to know is what are some of the steps that people use to come to the conclusion that they can say to themselves - "Gee Whiz! It looks like we can use a monad here!"

So when someone tells me... "(blah) has nothing to do with a monad...", it really doesn't help me answer my questions, which are:

- How do I go about determining what sort of patterns in programs could be expressed using monads?
- How can I write my own customised monad when I have identified the potential to use them?

I started a really long question here about monads if anybody is interested to help - [Map and Reduce Monad for Clojure... What about a Juxt Monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881471/map-and-reduce-monad-for-clojure-what-about-a-juxt-monad).

**Back to this Question:**

*When should we use a monad instead of a macro and vice-versa?*

- I've read articles and watched presentations that say... 'Monads are used for DSL abstraction' .... but most of the Clojure DSL libraries (eg. hiccup and korma) are using `defmacro` and it works great.

*And why do we need monads in Clojure if we have macros?*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I've been using Clojure for two years now and the only time I ever used monads was as an exercise to show that it could be done. I've never needed them for "real" code.

Monads are much more common in Haskell because:

- They are the idiomatic way of handling stateful computations. In Clojure, you typically handle state with [managed references](http://clojure.org/refs), so monads aren't needed nearly as much in Clojure.
- Likewise for IO: Clojure allows you to do IO directly without declaring it in your type, so you don't need the IO monad.

My suggestion would be to focus on standard functional programming in Clojure. Unless you see that you really *need* monads then I wouldn't invest too much time in trying to bring them in.

Macros are a slightly different issue: they are for compile-time code generation and extensions to the language syntax (which might include DSLs, although DSLs don't necessarily need macros). I use macros when both of the following are true:

1. I want to extend the language syntax in a way that significantly improves my ability to address a particular problem domain.
2. I *can't* get the same functionality with normal functions / function composition. Normal functions should be your first choice if possible: they are usually simpler to write and maintain.

P.S. If you are genuinely interested in monads for Clojure, here are two videos I personally found quite good:

- http://vimeo.com/20717301 (Brian Marick's excellent visual explanation of monads)
- http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Monads-Made-Easy

Comment: Just to add... in clojure monads are implemented using macros. So monads in clojure is just a library where as in other languages they has to be part of the language

Comment: In Haskell, the only part of monads that are "part of the language" (as opposed to the standard library) is the convenient do notation, and their use for I/O.

Comment: @Ankur, that makes no sense whatsoever. A monad abstraction is fully defined by two functions. If you are using a dynamically typed language, there's nothing stopping you from using this abstraction. If your language is statically and nominally typed, you'll need either higher kinds of first class modules to reliably represent this abstraction.

Comment: @Ankur, though again, F# for example gets away with its computation workflows, which are like "passable monads" implemented without higher kinds (because F# doesn't have them).

Comment: @Ankur, if you're talking about monad _comprehensions_, then yes, something of that sort would require a language level syntax, or a macro.

Comment: @mikera, monads are not only for handling statefull computations and in fact the State monad works great in combination with managed references. A Monad is such a general purpose design pattern that you may have used it (or invented it) without realizing it. For example, are you aware that sequences in Clojure are monads?

Comment: Isn't monad a "standard functional programming" pattern though? At least I thought it is ubiquitous in Haskell, Scala etc. Well, maybe my understanding of FP is not deep enough, and it's not that ubiquitous for all functional languages.

Answer (score 16):

Monads and macros have nothing in common. They are used for solving different problems. In Clojure, the monad library uses macros quite extensively for implementing the syntactical "user interface" to monads. You may well use monads to implement some library's functionally and than add a layer of macros for the external interface.

As for "when would one use monads in Clojure", I see two use cases:

1) To implement stuff that makes sense in more than one monad, in order to do the job
   only once and "plug in" the monad later. [Here](http://www.clojure.net/2012/03/26/Messin-with-core.logic/) is a nice illustration of this
   approach, though unfortunately (from a pedagogical point of view) for a rather
   non-trivial application: logic programming.

2) To implement a composition technique that can be formulated as a monad, in order to
   profit from the existing monad infrastructure.

Clojure has two built-in monads, "let" (identity monad) and "for" (sequence monad). Whenever you wish you could plug one of them into your code later on, you should use "domonad" instead. And whenever you wish you had something similar but not quite the same, you should consider writing your own monad.

This remains rather abstract, unfortunately. There aren't many published and polished code examples that use monads in Clojure at this moment. As more Clojurians get familiar with monads and more monad experts (usually coming from Haskell) use Clojure, this is likely to change. I have seen (but don't have at hand) monadic parsing done in Clojure, for example.

Comment: Regarding case 1): Here is a [nice article](http://software-ninja-ninja.blogspot.de/2014/04/5-faces-of-dependency-injection-in.html) about how monads provide a means for dependency injection in Clojure.

Answer (score 4):

@khinsen and @mikera answered the question so well that it's hardly to make any additional comments yet I think they missed one point (or I couldn't find it in their comments).

In Clojure macros are a part of the language. Use them or not, but they are there. In fact, you will often have no choice but use them since they make your applications more idiomatic (that's a feature of professional use of any language). They let you preprocess data structures that make up the application. They are akin to other language constructs in the sense they are included regardless of your needs.

Unlike macros, monads are not a part of Clojure. They are built using the language's constructs, namely macros. They are not included at runtime unless you insist on them being there. To me monads are design patterns for composing computations, and therefore they're akin to other design patterns you may be familiar with. You use design patterns to develop modular and cohesive applications and be it monads or macros or any other language construct you should know they exists and work with them for your good.

As to your question, macros work before monads ever kick in. Macros work at compilation phase - they change data structures to other data structures. Monads are a design pattern to compose computations. That's the difference. In Clojure, monads are written using macros (to make their use easier), and therefore people tend to say what you can do with monads you could easily achieve with macros. That's true as it comes out of monads design in Clojure, but the same might be said about macros themselves. You don't need to write new ones most of the time, and [the first rule of the macro club is to not write them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989374/help-me-write-a-clojure-macro-which-automatically-adds-metadata-to-a-function-de) at all, but still they're a part of the language and you should be very well aware of their applications.

See [How do Clojure programmers use Macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593931/how-do-clojure-programmers-use-macros) for more discussion about macros.